# fseek() return 0(success) but the read data is wrong

Tags: c, linux, file

I having trouble to read the right data using `fread` and `fwrite` using `fopen` and `fseek`.
The scenario:
1. write 4K data to offset 20.
2. read 4K data from offset 20.
3. write 4K data to offset 4K + 10.
4. read 4K data from offset 4K + 10.
I am init the Stream(`File*`) buffer to 256K - so the data stays in the buffer and does not actually written to the physical file.

```
typedef struct _MyFile {                 /* file descriptor */
    unsigned char fileBuf[256*1024];
    FILE *file;
} MyFile;

int main() {
    MyFile myFile;
    int res;
    int bufWrite[8*1024] = { 0 };
    int bufRead[8*1024];

    /* Open file for both reading and writing and reading */
    myFile.file = fopen("myfile.txt", "w+");

    /* Change the file internal buffer size */
    setvbuf(myFile.file, myFile.fileBuf, _IOFBF, sizeof(myFile.fileBuf));

    /* Seek to offset 20 of the file */
    res = fseek(myFile.file, 20, SEEK_SET);
    if (0 != res)
    {
       printf("1st fseek fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    bufWrite[0] = 1;
    /* Write data to the file(buffer) */
    res = (int)fwrite(bufWrite, 1, 4*1024, myFile.file);
    if (4+1024 != res)
    {
       printf("1st write fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    /* Seek to offset 20 of the file */
    res = fseek(myFile.file, 20, SEEK_SET);
    if (0 != res)
    {
       printf("2nd fseek fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    /* Read and display data */
    res = (int)fread(bufRead, 1, 4*1024, myFile.file);
    if (4+1024 != res)
    {
       printf("1st read fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    /* Seek to offset 4K + 10 of the file */
    res = fseek(myFile.file, 4*1024+10, SEEK_SET);
    if (0 != res)
    {
       printf("3rd fseek fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    bufWrite[0] = 2;
    /* Write data to the file(buffer) */
    res = (int)fwrite(bufWrite, 1, 4*1024, myFile.file);
    if (4+1024 != res)
    {
       printf("2nd write fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    /* Seek to offset 4K + 10 of the file */
    res = fseek(myFile.file,4*1024+10, SEEK_SET);
    if (0 != res)
    {
       printf("4th fseek fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    /* Read and display data */
    res = (int)fread(bufRead, 1, 4*1024, myFile.file);
    if (4+1024 != res)
    {
       printf("2nd read fails\n");
       goto Exit;
    }

    fclose(myFile.file);

Exit:
    return 0;        
}
```

The first `fread` has the right data, but the second `fread` does not,
the data for the second `fread` is 10 Zeros and only then the number 2.
What i'm doing wrong? is `fseek()` doesn't "know" to work with buffered Stream?

Comment: Assuming none of the calls fails, the code looks good (besides the missing prototypes for the functions used).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @alk how do you compile it?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -g  main.c -o main  -std=c11 -O0`

Comment: There is a minor flaw with passing `unsigned char` to `setvbuf`, so to be 100% correct change `unsigned char fileBuf[256*1024];` to be `char fileBuf[256*1024];` .

Comment: @alk I cast it, and still.
I have more info if it wwill help.
I disabled the `setvbuf` and change the `fopen` to `fopen("myfile.txt", "w");` and now the 2 write/read goes well but when i get the file info with `fstat` the `EOF` is 8212 instead of 8202

Comment: @alk I'm not using the `-std=c11`
Physical read happens(the `fread` after the disable of the `setvbuf` is phisical) but still why it is 8212 and not 8202, I think the `fseek` does not work well , or i'm not using it properly

Comment: This should work for any C dialect supported by GCC.

Comment: Does your real code provide error checking for all the `f*()` functions?

Comment: It's mostly never a bug in libc ... ;-)

Comment: Ok, so which GCC, which OS are you using? (`gcc --version; uname -a`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129724/discussion-between-eliad-cohen-and-alk).

Comment: To the other editor... don't edit someone else's code,  if it has mistakes then they might be part of the problem that is being asked about